# How can I set 2 background colors in a div

Tags: html, css

I need some help with setting `50% of the div` is color **blue** and the other `50% of the div` is color **red**, horizontally. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: There are very many ways to do that and (depending on the browser support requirement) the best would be to use a gradient with hard stops like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606260/blocky-gradient-effect-in-css3/27613861). You would need only two colors and stop at 50%.

Comment: Is using two divs a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

Might be over kill, but here it is http://jsfiddle.net/e9ypqy5t/6/

```
.repeat {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      180deg,
      blue,
      blue 50px,
      red 50px,
      red 100px 
    );
}
```

And here is the example using percentages http://jsfiddle.net/e9ypqy5t/8/

```
.repeat {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      180deg,
      blue,
      blue 50%,
      red 50%,
      red 100%
    );
}
```

This method will allow you to also add more lines of color like this: http://jsfiddle.net/e9ypqy5t/10/

```
.repeat {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      180deg,
      blue,
      blue 10%,
      red 10%,
      red 20%
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but there is a problem with adding contents inside the div. As I put some texts inside the div, the text overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this may be of use to you in this case:

```
#divname {
 background:linear-gradient(#ff0000,#0000ff);
}
```

Comment: No this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Pure css solution using `:after` pseudo selecter: http://jsfiddle.net/eLwdbgat/

```
div {
    width: 80%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}

div::after {
    content:'';
    position: fixed;
    height: 300px;
    width: 40%;
    left: 40%;
    background: lightgrey;
}
```

Comment: The text also overlaps in this div.

Answer (score 0):

You might be wanting a "gradient". Heres the code.

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  /* fallback */
  background-color: #1a82f7;

  /* Safari, Chrome 1-9 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1a82f7), to(#2F2727));

  /* Safari, Chrome 10+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

  /* Firefox*/
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

  /* IE */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

  /* Opera*/
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
```

Comment: No, this is not what I want. please read my question carefully.